# How to call a function that is defined in a component from another slice file in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a slice file that includes an async thunk function that returns an array based on API response. Some of this array elements are some `i` tags that trigger some functions to do something inside another component that is going to dispatch an async thunk. I don't know how can I call these functions (`handleShowForm` and `handleShowHistory`) when this slice file is not a child of that component that has the definition of these functions. I mean I can't pass them through props or contexts.

slice.js:

```js
export const getNomads = createAsyncThunk("applicant/getNomads", async(data) => {
  const {
    searchParam,
    pageNum
  } = data

  let nomadObj = {
    isPending: true,
    bodyArray: []
  }

  await axios.get(`https://demo.khedmatashayer-kj.ir/api/v1/nomad/${pageNum}?${searchParam}`, config)
    .then((response) => {
      ...
      let array = [];
      response.data && response.data.forEach((item) => {
        array = [...array, [ <i className="fa fa-edit edit"
          onClick={
            () => handleShowForm(item)
          }></i>, <i className="fa fa-file-text-o records"
          onClick={
            () => handleShowHistory(item.name, item.nomad_id)
          }></i>,
          ...
        ], ];
      });
      nomadObj = {
        isPending: false,
        bodyArray: array
      }
    })
  return nomadObj;
})

const applicantSlice = createSlice({
  ....
  }
})
```

My component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const handleShowForm = (arg) => {
    ..
  }

  const handleShowHistory = (arg1, arg2) => {
    ..
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNomads({
      searchParam: '',
      pagaNum: 1
    }))
  });

}
```

**Edit:**

My component that is using those i tags that are stored in state after getting response(in respond to Drew Reese):

```js
const UserInformationTable = () => {
    const {headArray, bodyArray, searchedBodyArray, statusStyle} = useContext(MyContext)
    const data = searchedBodyArray?.length > 0 ? searchedBodyArray : bodyArray; //searchedBodyArray comes from UserManagement
    const isPending = useSelector(selectIsPending)
    return(
        <table className='user-table'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {headArray.map((item, index) => {
                    return <th key={index}>{item}</th>
                })}
            </tr>
            </thead>
            {isPending ? <tbody><tr><td colSpan='100'><Loading /></td></tr></tbody> :
                <tbody>
                {(data?.length === 0 || data[0] === 'موردی یافت نشد') ? <tr><td className='empty-table' colSpan='100%'>موردی یافت نشد</td></tr> :
                    data?.map((item, index) => {
                        return(
                            <tr key={index}>
                                {item.map((entry, index1) => {
                                    return <td key={index1} className='table-entry' style={index1 === 12 ? statusStyle[index] : {}}>{entry}</td>
                                })}
                                <td>{toFarsiNumber(index + 1)}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
                </tbody>
            }
        </table>
    )
}
```

As you see, this is my component that's using those *i* tags and as it's a common component between multiple components and for example one of them doesn't need those *i* tags so I chose to store related values inside each component and then pass them to this table component. So this component and that component which had those two functions are different, actually this table component is a descendent of that MyComponent!

Comment: After data fetched, you need to dispatch data back to store. There is no onClick() in slice because they should be in MyComponent portion. For first few lines of MyComponent should be selector to subscribe data from store. https://dev.to/ifeanyichima/what-is-createasyncthunk-in-redux--mhe

Comment: The store will store whole array, and the index i will be used in MyComponent construction (ex. MyComponent(i)) then array[i] can be selected in a component.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you need a state manager in react the most popular are react context, react redux or zustand.

So you would need to manipulate the same value inside the functions.

For example:

```
const handleShowForm = (arg) => {
    setVisible(true)
    .
    .
}
```

Then in the createAsyncThunk in onClick you would call the same:

```
onClick={() => setVisible(true}
```

Where setVisible is a context exposed constant.

Context: https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext

Zustand: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand

This is one way, another one is to create a new file called helper.js and write the handleShowForm & handleShowHistory in there. Make sure you export them so you are able to call them in your files.

Comment: Isn't it obvious the OP is already using a state manager?

Comment: Actually I dont have access to that kind of state because my slice file is not a child or a descendent of that component. And it's also impossible to move my functions to another file because I use some local state inside those functions.

Comment: I didn't explain clearly enough I meant state manager that saves data to local storage. You say you have some local state inside functions if the state was saved in local storage or session storage that would solve your problem hence why I mention Zustand (They have built-in storage saving) which is easy to use.

Comment: @Dustaboy3 Thanks Dustaboy3:) but my states are local state like states related to my form inputs and as I know they would be better if I put them in those related components. right?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing JSX in state, this is a React anti-pattern. You should be storing ***the data*** into state, and selecting it in the UI and *then* render it to JSX at run-time where the callback functions are in scope.

Example Refactor:

Update the `applicantSlice` to handle the fulfilled `getNomads` action.

```js
export const getNomads = createAsyncThunk(
  "applicant/getNomads",
  async({ searchParam, pageNum }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://demo.khedmatashayer-kj.ir/api/v1/nomad/${pageNum}?${searchParam}`,
        config
      );
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

const applicantSlice = createSlice({
  ...,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(getNomads.pending, (state) => {
        state.isPending = true;
      })
      .addCase(getNomads.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.nomads = action.payload;
        state.isPending = false;
      })
      .addCase(getNomads.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.error = action.payload;
        state.isPending = false;
      });
  },
});
```

Update `MyComponent` to select the state and map the nomads to the `i` tags.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isPending, nomads } = useSelector(state => state.applicant);

  const handleShowForm = (arg) => {
    ...
  };

  const handleShowHistory = (arg1, arg2) => {
    ...
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNomads({
      searchParam: '',
      pagaNum: 1
    }));
  }, []); // <-- don't forget dependency array!!

  if (isPending) {
    return /* some loading UI */;
  }

  return (
    ...

    {nomads.map(nomad => (
      <React.Fragment key={nomad.nomad_id}>
        <i
          className="fa fa-edit edit"
          onClick={() => handleShowForm(nomad)}
        />
        <i
          className="fa fa-file-text-o records"
          onClick={() => handleShowHistory(nomad.name, nomad.nomad_id)}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}

    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks but my component that involves those two functions are different from the component that uses those i tags.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Well the statement still stands that storing JSX in state is anti-pattern. Can you edit your post to include a more representative code example for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks again, I edited my post to show more details.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi So where exactly are these functions that you want to be attached as click handlers in wherever the "bodyArray" data is rendered? Can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve]? It looks like you are mixing Redux with some provided Context so it might be unnecessarily complicating your code.